# Compile some tools in an old system with only gcc and limited tools

Tags: linux, gcc, sed, makefile

For some reasons I need to compile some tools for a quite old linux system.
Kernel version is 0.98, GCC: 2.2.2d, with some other tools, but unfortunately there is no sed, make, awk, ...
I need to compile them for it.

1st: I think about make a "make" first, though in "INSTALL" it says "we can make a make without make itself, by build.sh". But I need to "configure" first, "configure" needs sed, so unable to configure.

2nd: Then I head to sed, well, configure "sed" also needs sed itself.

I just wonder is that possible to solve this chicken-egg problem only in this system? Or I have to build a similar system (hopefully in the same age) to e.g. build a sed and migrate to it first?

Comment: I wonder if [busybox](https://www.busybox.net/) will work.

Comment: You can inspect the configure script and perform the necessary steps by hand in a text editor. Assuming you have a text editor :)

Comment: Also, kernel 0.98 is [literally 30 years old](https://kernelhistory.sourcentral.org/linux-0.98/). Wow.

Comment: Thanks all above, I guess better to build a similar compling system could not be a so hard thing. Well 0.98 kernel , I just can't figure out if there is some distributions at that time. Slackware or Debian...Maybe a little bit newer is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer by myself.
Probably, it is "no".
Or maybe "no" is an easier way to go.

I build another old system by qemu. the kernel level is about 1.1.x, well really far advance than 0.98 but usable. Cause the kernel didn't switch from aout to elf yet at least.

Finding a usable make version is not a easy thing. Per time the kernel 0.98 stayed at, I guess make-3.62 or make-3.63 could be good to use. But after testing, maybe 3.62 is more suitable. The oldest code I can fetch for now is 3.63, but fortunately 3.62-3.63 diff file can also be fetched. I use patch to reverse the change.

What really surprise me is that in make-3.62, there is no "configure", I have to customize the "Makefile" to make it through. Fortunately, I got that precious "make 3.62" eventually. Then migrate to the original old system, bomb, if you got make, you got everything easier.